# Function not getting called in useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, use-effect

I want these two functions to be called every time the component renders, but they are not being executed. And when I put the functions in the dependency array it results in an infinite loop. Any idea why they are not being called?

```js
  function PortfolioComponent() {
  const [requestedAssets, setRequestedAssets] = useState([]);
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function calcValue() {
      Promise.all(
        requestedAssets.map(async function (asset) {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(assetData(asset.AssetId));
            let cp = response.data.market_data.current_price.eur;
            let value = Number(cp) * Number(asset.Amount);
            return { ...asset, value: value, price: cp };
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data.error);
            throw error;
          }
        })
      )
        .then((newAssetArray) => {
          setAssets(newAssetArray);
          console.log(newAssetArray);
          console.log(assets);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    async function getAssets() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4200/assets");
        // Do as you wish with response here
        const assetResponse = response.data.rows;
        setRequestedAssets(assetResponse);
        console.log(requestedAssets);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data.error);
      }
    }

    getAssets();
    calcValue();
  }, []);
```

Also some weird behaviour I just discovered...

For example, this line of code:

```
        let cp = await response.data.market_data.current_price.eur;
```

When I remove the await keyword and save it in VS code, the data is retrieved as expected. However, when I refresh the browser the arrays are empty again. The same goes for when I add the await keyword again and save. The same thing happens.

Comment: I seems to me that you don't need the useEffect hook at all. Just call the functions directly.

Comment: The useEffect looks find to me. The issue looks to be with your two functions that get called. Try removing the contents of the functions and just put a console in there to see if its working

Comment: @FloRagossnig you don't want to call them directly in a react component because that would cause issues with re-renders

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. So, instead of having a useState variable for requestedAssets, I created a variable inside the getAssets method instead. I'm not exactly sure why this works and not the other way. But, if anybody could explain, that would be great.

```
 function PortfolioComponent() {
      //const [requestedAssets, setRequestedAssets] = useState([]);
      const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function getAssets() {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4200/assets");
          const requestedAssets = response.data.rows;
          console.log(requestedAssets);
    
          Promise.all(
            requestedAssets.map(async function (asset) {
              try {
                const response = await axios.get(assetData(asset.AssetId));
                let cp = response.data.market_data.current_price.eur;
                let value = Number(cp) * Number(asset.Amount);
                return { ...asset, value: value, price: cp };
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.response.data.error);
                throw error;
              }
            })
          )
            .then((newAssetArray) => {
              setAssets(newAssetArray);
              console.log(newAssetArray);
              console.log(assets);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    
        getAssets();
      }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommendation is to declare your functions inside the `useEffect`, see the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). If you keep scrolling in the docs, they even have an example similar to yours, with an `async` function.

If, for some reason, you do need to have your function declared outside the `useEffect`, you can use a `useCallback`, which allows you to declare them in the dependency array. Something like this:

```
const getAssets = useCallback(async() => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4200/assets");
    // Do as you wish with response here
    const assetResponse = response.data.rows;
    setRequestedAssets(assetResponse);
    console.log(requestedAssets);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.error);
  }
}, [requestedAssets])

useEffect(() => {
  getAssets()
}, [getAssets])
```

You can also see the section **Do I need to specify functions as effect dependencies or not?** in this [blog here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) for more information.

PS: This blog is from Dan Abramov, one of the creators of React, so reliable source ;)

Comment: This is causing an infinite loop

Comment: Did you first try to declare your function inside the useEffect? That should not cause an infinite loop. Or are you using the callback approach?

Comment: If you are using the callback, you need to check your dependencies. For example, the `getAsset` function is changing the state of `requestedAssets`, so that needs to be a dependency. Another option is to check if `requestedAssets` is an empty array (inside the useEffect), before trying to run it. Maybe you can give more details? I also updated the answer to include the dependency (missed that)

Comment: I updated the question. I declared the function inside useEffect, but still not working. The functions seem to be getting called as the console.logs are getting logged to the console but the arrays are empty? I will provide a screen shot

Comment: I also tried the callBack approach and added requested assets as a dependence but that just is an infinite loop also.

Comment: I have updated the question with some weird behaviour that I just discovered that might help. Could we go to a private chat? :)